# Why does my expression index not accept the same syntax that a query does?

Tags: postgresql

This query works as expected:

```
# select start_date + (duration * (interval '1 second')) from mytable;
      ?column?       
---------------------
 2016-06-30 19:00:00
(1 row)
```

But then when trying to create an expression index with it, there is a syntax error:

```
# create index on mytable (start_date + (duration * (interval '1 second')));
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "+"
LINE 1: ...reate index on mytable (start_date + (duratio...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an additional set of parentheses. It's a bit awkward, but it's how postgres knows to parse it as an expression:

```
# create index on mytable (start_date + (duration * (interval '1 second')));
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "+"
# create index on mytable ((start_date + (duration * (interval '1 second'))));
CREATE INDEX
```